# Can not run `Karma` tests on Linux server

Tags: phantomjs, karma-runner

I setup `karma` tests on my project and runs well on my Mac OSX.
However it fails on my linux server.

server info:
    $ uname -a
    Linux sz-mc-01 3.13.0-65-generic #106-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 2 22:08:27 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

error output:

```
26 04 2016 15:06:38.065:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
26 04 2016 15:06:38.069:ERROR [launcher]: No binary for PhantomJS browser on your platform.
Please, set "PHANTOMJS_BIN" env variable.
```

I set "PHANTOMJS_BIN" and rerun, the error is

```
$ export PHANTOMJS_BIN=node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs 

26 04 2016 15:20:32.857:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
26  04 2016 15:20:32.935:ERROR [phantomjs.launcher]: internal/child_process.js:274
var err = this._handle.spawn(options);
                     ^

TypeError: Bad argument
at TypeError (native)
at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:274:26)
at exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/jenkins/workspace/Website_BridgePlus/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs:22:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:429:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)

26 04 2016 15:20:32.937:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start PhantomJS
```

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe this solution will work https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/44535 `npm install phantom phantomjs` But that's not telling why it doesn't now...

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem related to `fsevents`. As the output contains:   `npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.11`

Comment: Did you commit the node_modules ? Some dependancies are compiled and will not work if you change setup. You have to do a npm install.

Comment: @BorisCharpentier, No I didn't commit the node_modules. I run `npm install` on the server.